# webRTCConnection failed between two Windows devices

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webrtc, p2p

I have created a WebRTC client and a signaling server. The two work perfectly when establishing a connection between two Macs or between a Mac and a Windows.

However, when trying to establish a connection between two Windows (10) machines, the ice connection fails.

Below you'll find two screenshots of the WebRTC helper in Chrome (`chrome://webrtc-internals`). Both screenshots are taken from the Windows machine and the connection was in both cases initialised from there: The first one is from the (failed) connection to the other Windows machine and the one the right is from the (successful) connection to the Mac.

[image]

As you can see, signaling works fine as the offer and answer get exchanged smoothly. There must be something wrong with the ice candidates.
Does anyone have an idea on how to further debug this issue?

Additional infos:
 - All devices run the latest version of Chrome (v70)
 - The devices are in the same network (no NAT or STUN needed)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons could be a Guest-Wifi or a Firewall (Windows?) on your machine.
I would try the same constellation with a TURN-Server and it should work finde. Once your Application should be accessible from outside you'll need it anyway.

By the way - Chrome 70 is not the latest.